# Angular 5 multithreading

Tags: multithreading, angular5

We are making a library to be consumed by applications (through cdn).
We want to perform true asynchronous http calls within the library using the HttpClient from @angular/common/http.

These should not block the main UI thread or the ajax calls made by the consumer. We would use this to log auditing information and time measurements to the back-end.

Because if we use web workers we can't access all the Angular stuff.
We also want to avoid to load the entire UI in a web worker. The consumers of the library should not be aware of web workers.

What is the best way to achieve this in Angular 5?

Comment: if your calls are asynchronous why would they block the UI?

Comment: It should be multithreaded and javascript is single-threaded. So if a call is calling the back-end to save something in the database the remainer of the app has to wait for it.

Comment: Sure it waits but it continues code execution and once a response comes back it processes it but continues on. You said it yourself Javascript is pretty much single threaded. You can use web workers for the continuous server calls to track your stats but the main thread is going to have to orchestrate it all.

Comment: Image the application is doing 3 ajax calls in a promise chain. Call 2 has to wait till call 1 is finished and call 3 has to wait till call 2 is finished. Now with the library we would add a call in between each call because we want to save measurements. So you get call 1, call 1 b, call 2, call 2 b, call 3, call 3 b. Now call 2 has to wait for call 1 and call 1 b to finish and call 3 has to wait for call 1, call 1 b, call 2 and call 2 b to finish. Meaning the calls made by the consumer have to wait longer. We want to avoid this. By sending the 1b, 2b, 3b calls through a web worker.

Comment: if each of the calls depend on each other as in needing response data in the next call how would using multithreading solve that issue? If the calls don't depend on each others data eg: call 1 data isn't used for call 2s request then there is no need to chain. Maybe you could give a detailed example in your question of the types of calls and stats calls you are making.

Comment: See this article: http://techslides.com/html5-web-workers-for-ajax-requests